# improving order of scripts/styles in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have ran a test on GTMetrix.com and got the following results that I am keen to resolve:

```
Defer parsing of JavaScript
    https://cdn.livechatinc.com/js/embedded.20180601111352.js (298.1KiB)
    https://www.supplementgenie.co.uk/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/d5kgllyt/hkkjp.js (206.0KiB)
    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js (85.8KiB)
    https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js (29.3KiB)
    https://www.mysite.co.uk/ (10.9KiB of inline JavaScript)
```

and:

```
Optimize the order of styles and scripts
    https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
    https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700
    https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
    https://www.mysite.co.uk/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/7nwfrtef/hkkjp.css
```

I am very keen to sort these out... I am relatively new to webdesign and my website is in its infancy and anything I can do to improve its SEO would be a massive help.

The external JS and CSS has currentlt been added in ...

I have tried enqueueing the external JS and CSS as so

```
function external_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('googleapis', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.11.2', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.2', false);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'external _scripts' );  

function external_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('bs_css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font_awsom_css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'external _styles' )
```

However it appears to break the site and images etxc do not load.

I would really appreciate some help with properly calling external scripts and styles in wordpress and also how to sort the order of scripts / styles from plugins

Comment: jQuery library can't depend on itself and you named it `googleapis` but bootstrap script is looking for dependency `jquery`. My bet is your template already includes jquery also

Comment: Also WordPress loads a jquery version for you if you want to use that your own remove the other or you'll have two and that can cause conflicts and as charlietfl mentioned that third parameter is to reference any dependencies

Comment: @charlietfl The only scripts/styles that the parent theme uses is the font-awsome.css. I have now removed that. but my question still stands for the others. is there anything that you know of that could help?

Comment: Call jQuery `'jquery'` when you enqueue it and don't make it dependent on itself. Then your bootsrap dependency would be correct

Comment: @charlietfl would that still work if there was a file from the parent themes function.php which is also called `'jquery'`?

Comment: Ok and that's what I was suggesting above that it may already be included in template. You only want one version of jQuery.js so use the template version and get rid of your new one